# does asp.net webMethod must return string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

Couldn't google it.
Does asp.net webMethod must return string? or it can return void?

Comment: what's the issue? did you try to return void and check if it works?

Comment: void didn't work. Changing to string didn't help.

Comment: Then show the code. `void` should work.

Comment: You should post some code. It should work in both ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods exposed in a web service can return any type, provided the return type be `XmlSerializable`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman : The kind of serialization required for using web services in .net 2.0 is XML, as the underlying communication mean is SOAP, isn't it ? It'd be `[Serializable]` if the data had to be input in a binary serializer, wouldn't it ?

Comment: ASMX service (from Fx 1.0 and up) use the SoapFormatter class that relies on [Serializable].

Comment: No, it uses Xml. SoapFormater != BinaryFormatter

Answer (score 1):

WebMethod is an attribute for a service. It is not a method type.

Comment: Sorry I felt it would be sufficient to inform the OP that it was being used incorrectly.